# Maximum number of lines in an Oracle Package

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

Can anyone tell me the maximum number of lines in an Oracle Package?
What is recommended by Oracle?
What is programmatically possible?

Comment: 10G. Is there any difference across versions?

Comment: In this question the  answer is no, there is no difference at all between 10g and 11g

Answer (score 5):

From the chapter [PL/SQL Program Limits](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/limits.htm#LNPLS018) in the 11.2 documentation:

> In the shared memory pool, a package specification, ADT specification,
>   standalone subprogram, or anonymous block is limited to 67108864
>   (2**26) DIANA nodes which correspond to tokens such as identifiers,
>   keywords, operators, and so on. This allows for ~6,000,000 lines of
>   code unless you exceed limits imposed by the PL/SQL compiler

This is [identical in 10g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/limits.htm#LNPLS018). It's important to remember that the more lines you have the slower your code will be to compile and the longer it will take to run when executed as more lines of code generally means more operations to perform.

Diana stands for Descriptive Intermediate Attributed Notation for Ada; it is

> ... a tree-structured intermediate language. It is defined using a
>   metanotation called Interface Definition Language (IDL). DIANA is used
>   internally by compilers and other tools.

See also:

- [Who is diana, and why won't she let my database objects compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764656/who-is-diana-and-why-wont-she-let-my-database-objects-compile)

Answer (score 2):

Logical databas limit 8i and 9i [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96536/ch44.htm) 10g [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/limits003.htm#sthref3594), 11g [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits003.htm)

Comment: But it says that Procedure size is limited to 2000 - 3000. I found package with more than 4000 lines. In other 11g document I found that a package spec or object type spec is limited to 67108864 DIANA nodes. So it says that Oracle allows about 6 millions lines in package. The same size is in 10g too.